# Can Amazon Elastic Transcoder convert a sequence of images into a video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I have sequence of images that must be converted to video:

`image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, etc...`

Can it be done using AWS Elastic Transcoder ?

If not, what would be your preferred AWS tool for this kind of job ?

Comment: Bob, it looks like you ask a lot of questions but don't follow up and accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Amazon Elastic Transcoder converts (transcodes) media files from their source format to versions that will playback on devices like smartphonese, tablets and PCs.

[Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/)

I am not aware of another Amazon tool that will meet your objectives. You will need to look into a third party product for this. Most home movie video software will take images and convert them into a video slideshow.